# How to sort by sections two columns as due date and code?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I currently have the following table:

[image]

How can I sort the 1st table by Due date and then by customer code, keeping the colors of each customer code always together. The goal will be to have the listing of each customer organized by due date from oldest to newest.

[image]

I tried by Excel menu (Sort and filter--> personalized sort), but this way didn't function. Is it possible by other way? For example, vba code or by excel funtions?

Comment: This is more a questin for Superuser - as no VBA or formulas are involved. Nevertheless: you have to use custom sort: First sort = customer code (ascending), second sort = Due date (descending)

Answer (score 1):

The only answer without vba that i know of using sort with 2 level. You Will just click on Sort in data tab then press  on +add level button first sort should be due date and then the second one should be customer code
[image]

Comment: I tried by this way, however final result is different than what i want, because it doesn't join the customer codes, everything is mixed up. By vba code is it possible? If yes, you can help me, please?